# Packagist package keeps auto-updating after renaming it (abandon+new)

Tags: github, packagist

Packagist does not support package renaming, and the [official procedure](https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/47) is rename it in composer, resubmit and abandon the old one.

If the old package is abandoned, why it keeps auto-updating versions with new releases from GitHub? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "auto-updating", and how is that related to Composer (which is only the program to download packages)?

Comment: The hook that keeps updating the Packagist information every time there is a new release on GitHub. Composer is just the tool in between, I will remove the tag.

Comment: If the package is abandoned, why are there new versions published? Is the same package name, or the same repository, still in use?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm doing a package renaming. Abandoning and resubmitting with a different name is the official way.